# jQuery homemade slideshow code seems to be not picking up the current context of the images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this is going to be a simple problem but I've been looking at it all day and struggling to find an answer so hopefully you  wonderful people will be able to help.

I have created my own javascript function making use of jQuery to create a slideshow. I know there are loads of free ones out there that I could use but the few that i tried did not allow multiple slideshows on the same page and that got me thinking that this shouldn't be too difficult to do.

On the page I have 2 of these div elements containing images

```
<div class="slider">
    <img src="./images/Hashimadisaster.png" alt="" title="Hashima Island" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-842">
    <img src="./images/DSCN3674-1024x767.jpg" alt="" title="Legs glued together" class="alignnone size-large wp-image-834">
    <img src="./images/DSCN3672-768x1024.jpg" alt="" title="The front and rear legs together standing on an Eldar Falcon" class="alignnone size-large wp-image-836">
    <img src="./images/DSCN3671-1024x768.jpg" alt="" title="Left rear leg glued into position and balanced to stand on its own" class="alignnone size-large wp-image-835">
    <img src="./images/conseptiual-drawing-for-titan-base-1024x609.jpg" alt="Conceptual drawing for titan base" title="Conceptual drawing for titan base" class="alignnone size-large wp-image-841">
</div>
```

and the javascript code

```
1. function slidermethod(){
2.  var HeightOfBox= 400;
3.  var timeoutmilliseconds = 3000;
4.  if($('.slider').length){
5.      $('.slider').each(function(){
6.          $(this).css("position","relative");
7.          $(this).children('img').css("position","absolute").css("top","0").css("left","0");  
8.          if($(this).children('img').length){
9.              if($(this).children(".currentslide").length == 0){
10.                 //alert($(this).children("img").length);
11.                 //alert("1");
12.                 // this seems to occur every time it is called
13.                    $(this).children('img:first').addClass(".currentslide");
14.             }
15.             else{
16.                 if($(this).children('.currentslide').next().length)    {    
17.                     alert("2");
18.                     var nextchild = $(this).children('.currentslide').next();
19.                     $(this).children('img').removeClass('.currentslide');
20.                     $(nextchild).addClass(".currentslide");
21.                 }else{                  
22.                     alert("3");
23.                     $(this).children('img').removeClass('.currentslide');
24.                     $(this).children('img:first').addClass(".currentslide");
25.                 }
26.             }               
27.         }
28.         $(this).children('img').css("height",HeightOfBox + "px");
29.         $(this).css("height",HeightOfBox + "px");           
30.     });
31.     setTimeout("slidermethod();",timeoutmilliseconds); 
32.        // every 3 seconds call this method
33. }   
34.}
35.slidermethod(); // call the method
```

The code runs without any errors popping up and grabs all the images, resizes them and places them on top of one another. I have a css stylesheet which has .currentslide as z-index:2; and all the other images as 1. but when it gets to the bottom of the code, there is a settimeout() which calls the same method again 3 seconds later but it always seems to go into the if statement

```
9.    if($(this).children(".currentslide").length == 0){
```

but if I firebug it I can see that the first image in the group of images has the class of "currentslide", so this should not be 0. not really sure why this is not working as expected.

Comment: why using jquery & not making a plugin ($.fn.extend({slider:function(){}}) ? why not using events & then a trigger in your timeout instead of a call to the full function (line 6 & 7 are run for every slide change while you just need to run it once)? instead of solving this bug i'd rethink your code first to make it more logical & efficient

Comment: @mikakun While that sounds like a good idea, however I am quite new to jQuery (hense the hybrid jQuery and javascript) and don't really understand your comment which will make it difficult to do what you ask. While I do plan on learning some more advanced topics in time and will most likely re-write the code once I have gotten it working even inefficiently. I don't see how moving the timeout into a jQuery plugin will solve the context problem. Though I do agree that lines 6&7 should not need to be run every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is a mistake here

```
.addClass(".currentslide")
```

should be

```
.addClass("currentslide")
```

in all your addclass/removeclass you made the same mistake

and a nicer path to start your plugin

```
$.fn.extend({

    slider : function() {
       $(this).each(function() {
           var $sldr=$(this);

            $sldr.css("position","relative")
                 .find("img").css("position","absolute").css("top","0").css("left","0").end()
                 .find("img:first-child").addClass("currentslide").end()

                .on("nextslide",function() {
                        var $current = $sldr.find(".currentslide").removeClass("currentslide")
                        if ($current.next().get(0)) $current.next().addClass("currentslide") 
                        else    $sldr.find("img:first-child").addClass("currentslide")

                  });        
                 setTimeout(function(){$sldr.trigger("nextslide"),3000 });
        });
   return this;
   }
});
   $(".slider").slider();
```

edit to add that i copied your code but you should move those css properties in your css file, they don't need to be set in the plugin, so it'd become

```
$sldr.on("nextslide",function() {
                        var $current = $sldr.find(".currentslide").removeClass("currentslide")
                        if ($current.next().get(0)) $current.next().addClass("currentslide") 
                        else    $sldr.find("img:first-child").addClass("currentslide")

                  }).find("img:first-child").addClass("currentslide");
```

Comment: Thank you this is awesome, I will try this and hopefully be marking your answer as the correct one tonight.

Comment: well it is the correct one concerning your bug(the extra "."); the rest is bonus for you to get better understanding of jquery

Answer (score 2):

The reason your checks are failing is because .children() is returning 0.

Do something like this instead:

```
if($('.slider img').hasClass('currentslide').length < 1){ /*your code*/ }
```

I agree with mikakun. you sure are jumping into the DOM a lot by calling $(this). Set $('.slider') to a variable and use the variable where you need to.

Comment: returning 0 because of the extra "." in his add/removeclass